# How to prohibit usage of classes with certain annotation

Tags: java, checkstyle, pmd, archunit

In our organizations we've got several microservices and lots of libraries.

Some libraries define "public" classes that are not intended for public usage - only inside library in multiple packages (thus can't be package-private)

I'd like to add something similar to Kotlin's "internal" modifier - a checkstyle rule/annotation processor/test component that verifies that consumer applications don't import these classes.

for example, I will mark them as @ForInternalUsageOnly or put into package com.ourorg.mylib.internal_usage

what can be a non-copy-pasted (e.g. a jar or a gradle task) implementation that verifies that such classes are not imported? Preferably - on compilation level

Comment: http://errorprone.info/bugpattern/RestrictedApiChecker ?

Comment: oh, another static analysis tool :) thank you, will check it out

Comment: this is not possible to achieve by checkstyle. It does not work with bytecode, only works with plain text. So you cannot provide some checkstyle stuff to 3rd parties to warn them about it unless they dont setup such checks themselves.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you should be using the Java 9+ `module` feature, and its ability specify what classes are exposed outside of a given module.

Here are some references to get you started:

- [Understanding Java 9 Modules](https://www.oracle.com/corporate/features/understanding-java-9-modules.html)
- [A Guide to Java 9 Modularity](https://www.baeldung.com/java-9-modularity)

and there are lots of tutorials and videos.

---

While it should be possible to do what you propose using annotations and a checker, I can't recommend any practical examples.

Comment: in theory - yes, but from what I researched, 
java modules + gradle + spring boot is not something that will work :)

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve something like this with ArchUnit easily, your ArchRule would be something like -

```java
@ArchTest                                                  
public static final ArchRule customArchRule = noClasses()   
    .should()                                               
    .dependOnClassesThat()                                  
    .areAnnotatedWith(ForInternalUsageOnly.class);
```

Assuming you are using it with JUnit 5 or 4, classes in `noClasses()` are determined by `@AnalyzeClasses`, you can read more about setting up and using ArchUnit from [here](https://www.archunit.org/userguide/html/000_Index.html#_junit_support).